# Jquery - table.row(tr) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to use [datatables jQuery plugin](https://datatables.net), but having trouble and I can't figure out why is that happening.

I got an action column on my table:

```
table = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: dataUrl,
    deferRender: true,
    esponsive: true,
    pageLength: 15,
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    stateSave: true,
    filter: true,
    language: {
        paginate: {
            next: " ",
            previous: " ",
            first: "First",
            last: "Last"
        }
    }

$(document).on('click', ".details-control2", function () {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent(); // <-- finds the correct tr
    var row = table.row(tr);
    console.log(row); // <-- undefined, why??? 'table' is recognized correctly
}
```

**Update - Table's HTML:**

```
<tbody>
<tr id="row_0" role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1"></td>
    <td><input type="image" src="/images/plus.png" class="details-control2"> </td>
    <td>rasplap.dll</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>WIN7X86</td>
    <td>DLL</td>
    <td>4/4/2015 3:45:45 PM</td>
    <td>4/4/2015 5:38:32 PM</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Any suggestions? Please tell me if any info is missing.

Comment: provide `html` for table, Are you using `dataTables` ?

Comment: What is `table`? Does it have a `row()` method? Unless your code is using some plugins you've not mentioned, you've got some big syntax issues

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, look my update, i use jquery datatable

Comment: dont you think `tr` is already row you want, why you still need this `var row = table.row(tr);` what is your purpose

Comment: The code works fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9Loqksyb/** there is nothing suspicious about your approach (I would suggest alternatives for finding the tr, but that is another story)  so the problem must be rely elsewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).parentNode.parentNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in datatable forum: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11836/getting-data-on-click

I hope this helps:

```
$(document).on('click', ".details-control2", function () {

    var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        data = table._(row),
        id = data[0].id;  

    //do something with your id
    //Get the position of the current data from the node
    var aPos = table.fnGetPosition(id);//you many need to use ('#' + id)

    // Get the data array for this row
    var aData = table.fnGetData(id[0]);//you many need to use ('#' + id[0])
});
```

Comment: it doesnt work like that. take a look here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: I think they have this use: `var data = table.row( 0 ).data();` in their api: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data() , I check before I posted